Build VueJs into Spring Boot, getting error "Whitelabel Error Page"
I'm currently working on a web app with VueJs for the front, and Spring Boot for the back. When I'm working, I launch each part on its own, and it works. To deploy the app, I want to build the front end to launch it from the back end. I'm building my VueJs and I have a few files in the dist folder.
My problem comes when I want to access the app via: localhost:8882.
I've tried placing the contents of the dist folder files in different folders in the back (resources/public, resources/static, resources/templates, resources/META-INF/resources). But every time I get the error: Whitelabel Error Page. And in the spring boot logs:
No mapping for GET /.
No endpoint GET /.
I've looked on lots of forums and on YouTube, but nothing has solved my problem.
I'm using JAVA21 and Spring Boot version "3.2.3".
Thanks in advance
I've tried running just the front end on a server, and it works. So I think the problem is with the Spring Boot configuration

WhiteLabel page error comes when spring have some error and don't have any manual handelling from developer side, if you are getting this error message
No endpoint GET / means there is no method (in controller configured) to hit that endpoint (url which you are hitting ) , for example you might be hitting http://localhost:8882/ ( which is not mapped to any point in controller) (in general controllers have end points mentioned like /hit , /do-this , /ABC/123 or anything . and the endpoint you are trying to hit is just / , which is not configured to any of the endpoint for now .
try to hit the correct end point from browser might solve your problem.
or another possibilty is that you marked method with(/ endpoint) other request then GET
for this
check the part where you have written the method ("/")
@GetMapping("/")

Thank you for your response. Finaly i have used @GetMapping like you say and it's works.
But it's not ideal because i have to setup 1 route for index.html, 1 route for assets files and 1 for svp
